# Java bug Cant retain the the value of counter

Tags: java, loops, mapreduce

my counter value is being over write every time.Cant figure out the way to keep the value incremented. this a map Reduce code. Need to set the value of counter with profileId. thanks

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String profile;
    String pos = null;
    int count=0;
    StringTokenizer inputKey=new StringTokenizer(value.toString()," ,");

    while(inputKey.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String input=inputKey.nextToken();
        System.out.println("the input is "+ input);

        if(!input.endsWith("</id>")) {
            textInput.set(input);
            count++;
            System.out.println("value of count is " + count);
        } else {
            profile=input.substring(4,15);
            profileId.set(profile);
        }

        /*count=+count;
          int index=value.toString().indexOf(count);
          pos=Integer.toString(index);
          System.out.println("the position is " + pos);
        */
        System.out.println("the index for each word is " + pos ); 
        context.write(textInput, new Text(profileId + ", " + pos));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by overwritten? What is some sample output and then say what you expect

Comment: You never change the counters' value - assuming counter = `count`...

Comment: I suppose you mean the `count` variable do you? Furthermore I suppose by "incrementing" you mean `count=+count` in the commented code (which is just wrong - to increment, you should have `count++` or `count += 1`) ?

Comment: ok the sample out put is --- John ||Q1S5WLipQW2, 1|||INIcE89C561, 1|||INIcE89C560, 1||  As in this example 1 after "," shows the occurence of word "john " from 3 different text files.

Comment: @ peter . Yes i ment count and i use count++ in if condition.

Comment: @Rohit Haritash: I do not see a count++ in the snippet you provided.

Comment: @Windle <record>
<id>Q1S5WLipQW2</id>
<cv_text>Q1S5WLipQW  
Joseph    
John  
Software Systems Engineer at Texas Instruments  
Bengaluru Area, India  ... and so on. Data is present in 3 different files.

Comment: private Text textInput=new Text();  // Key It is a key in the key,value pair.